# Seemingly valid UTF-8 character is breaking PHP json_encode()

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I know there are other answers out there, but none of the solutions seem to work for me: I get no return value from my JSON conversion when trying to encode an array via PHP.

- Both MySQL database and table column are encoded with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
- I set `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");` inside the PHP script I send the data with.
- On records without accented characters, everything works fine. On the same records that break, if I swap the accented character for a non-accented version to test it, it works. I have narrowed the issue down to any accented / non-latin character.
- I have various multi-lingual words saved in the database, many with accented characters. As an example, I'll use

  > Stade Municipal Georges Lefévre

  In the database, everything looks good. When I get the data from the database, it looks good:

  ```
  Array
  (
     [id] => 12345
     [name] => Stade Municipal Georges Lefévre
  )
  ```

However, when I `json_encode()` that, I get an empty String for the array element `name`. I used to get no return at all, but updated my call with an addition parameter:

```php
json_encode($Array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
```

I get the following error output from `json_last_error_msg()`:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

I just don't understand how it is incorrectly encoded at this point. I've tried almost every solution I've seen in other answers and just nothing seems to work to not break this output of JSON.

Comment: If you want UTF8 why are you using `ISO-8859-1` at any point?

Comment: A quick check of that [specific string](https://3v4l.org/IuWTp) shows it can be encoded, so your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: @user3783243 using `ISO-8859-1` right now as it was a suggestion from another answer, and didn't change the output of anything or make it different without it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas hmm... that is interesting. That is the only character that is accented in my whole json object (which is about 200 lines in full), and when that one character is changed to just an `e` it all works as expected, so I really don't think it's anything else, but I'll dig deeper on some other things.

Comment: Try `mb_detect_encoding()` on that string; maybe it's coming in from the database in Unicode or some other encoding.

Comment: Perform [`bin2hex`](https://php.net/bin2hex)`( $array['name'] )` and include the result in your question, so we technically (instead of only optically) see how `é` is encoded. I'm sure `json_encode()` tells you the truth.